# Prevent NavigationDrawer from opening on Home Button Click

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a NavigationDrawer for my main activity, in one instance I show a fragment and the "Hamburger menu" changes into an arrow.

I disabled the ability to open the drawer via swipe when that fragment is shown by using this

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

and it works fine but now the problem is the user can still open the drawer by clicking the home button "Arrow". I want the arrow to act as the back button and not open the drawer so how can I stop the drawer from opening?

Comment: is `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`  ?

Comment: @SachinGutte yes it is

Comment: are you using an ActionBar or Toolbar? or setting a Toolbar as a supportActionBar? also Is this done in your fragment? or the hosting Activity

Comment: @inner_class7 setting toolbar as SupportActionBar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you need to use [setNavigationOnClickListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) on toolbar to override drawer behavior.

Like -

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        // logic to decide if drawer open/close, or pop fragment etc
     }
});
```

This does prevents drawer from opening by clicking on icon. But it does open by swiping. But that you already taken care of. So this should work.

**Note** This works only after you set `ActionBarDrawerToggle` by calling

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,  toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){ ...
```

Comment: ahhhh that was the problem, I tried that before but I never got the callback, but like you said I have to do it after I call that constructor

Answer (score 1):

Put this on your Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getId() == android.R.id.home){
        doSomething(); //can be a finish()
    }
}
```

Or, [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26590019/2823516)

```
mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popStackIfNeeded();
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: setToolbarNavigationClickListener never got called but also that code in the onClick is going to hide the home button which I do not want, the drawer indicator should act as the back button like in the Gmail app

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding onOptionsItemSelected check for the id android.R.id.home and call finish() to go back to your previous activity.

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected never gets called and I do not want to finish the activity I am in, I just want to remove the fragment

Comment: About it not getting called, do you have statements the getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); in your activity. If not, could you please try adding these ? About the finish() thing, you can use your fragment manager to remove your fragment.

Comment: adding those made no difference

Comment: Before changing the hamburger to arrow, on pressing the hamburger, does your code through onOptionsItemSelected() ?

Comment: No it does not, however reading the link from @joaquin one person suggested I am using the wrong constructor. I changed my constructor and not my onOptionsItemSelected gets called in my Activity but I still cannot stop the drawer from opening

Comment: Are you returning super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); ? For the case of your arrow, return true.

Comment: I had to do some logic in there and yes now I am, so it is now working correctly

Answer (score 0):

try to override on options item select.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case android.R.id.home :
                // do what you want
                return true;
          }
          return true;
       }
```

Comment: like I said to everyone else this does not get called