# Toolbar back button is not calling onOptionsItemSelected Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

I can able to see the back button in the toolbar but when i click, nothing happens. It is not going to `onOptionsItemSelected` but when i remove the whole implementation of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` then the back button is working fine. I need to switch between both when i needed. Thank in advance.

```
package demo.sample.com.sample.base;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_digi_care);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        mDrawer.setFocusable(false);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);


        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Logger.i(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected called");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Logger.i(TAG, "Back button pressed"); //Never getting called
                //onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And i finally got a solution. instead getting toolbar home button click on`onOptionsItemSelected()` it can be handled through `DrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener`.

```
mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // event when click home button
                Log.d("cek", "home selected");
            }
        });
```

Thanks to @meow meo. Source - [Cannot catch toolbar home button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event/31499604#31499604][1])

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to fire when the toggle Button is clicked, you need to use the four-parameter constructor for `ActionBarDrawerToggle` that doesn't take a `Toolbar` argument.

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity,
                             DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
                             int openDrawerContentDescRes,
                             int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

Otherwise, the toggle will just handle the drawer opening/closing directly itself.