# NavigationView actionaBar onOptionsItemSelected R.id.home not triggered

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I want to implement the up button in an android application with only one activity that changes its content with different fragment.
I used the default navigation drawer activity provided by android studio where i added a frameLayout to the content_main.
In the fragment where i want the up botton to be shown i added this line of code in the onCreateView method:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

ad this line in the onCreate method:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and i added the method to catch the click of it:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Log.w("second fragment","clicked back");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

in the activiy i set onCreateOptionsMenu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

but the click of it isn't triggered.
I tried to add a setting button and it is triggered.
I already read a lot of question about this but i can't figure out how to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

`setHasOptionsMenu(true)` should be called in method `onCreate()` to let the FragmentManager know that your fragment needs to receive options menu callbacks.

Comment: I put it bu i forgot to add in the question

Comment: How do you implement `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: All things seem all right: you have called setHasOptionsMenu, you use android.R.id.home instead of R.id.home,  onCreateOptionsMenu is OK. I have no idea. orz....

Comment: already tried both and nor work.The strange thing is that even in the activity `onOptionsItemSelected` on `R.id.home` isn't triggered

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use [this constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,%20int,%20int)) for `ActionBarDrawerToggle` which takes a `Toolbar` as a parameter. If you are using this constructor, `onOptionsItemSelected` will not be called if you click on the indicator. There are questions/answers regarding this problem, for example:

[AppCompat v7 Toolbar onOptionsItemSelected not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588917/appcompat-v7-toolbar-onoptionsitemselected-not-called)

But for me, none of them worked perfectly so I used the Toolbar-specific constructor and here it's a **workaround** for my case. I put a transparent view on top of the toolbar which is "visible" only when I show the back button and I handle the click myself (calling `onBackPressed()` in my case).

I know it's a kind of hack, but it needed and worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/main_background">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutMainContent"
                android:layout_below="@id/appBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- The important view -->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewFakeBack"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank's, at the end i have found another workaround from various question, because also for me nor work

Answer (score -1):

Try by using switch(...) case statement.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //this will make Hamburger button clickable.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    //this will make the HomeAsUpIndicator button clickable.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
           Log.w("second fragment","clicked back");
           break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, in my case a whole onOptionsItemSelected is not called.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why should a switch have anything to do with the problem?